# AS3 Text link event not working

Tags: actionscript-3

quick question regarding the TextEvent:LINK.

It stopped working recently when I switched my interface and I'm not quite sure why or how to fix it.

I have a movie clip which contains a text area and a scroll handler.  3 of these are added to my interface, although only 1 at a time is active in the display, depending on which tab you click.

All of that works fine, but once I change the chat object (textfield and scrollbar) in the display, it seems to stop working, and I'm not quite sure why.  I'm not creating new instances all together, just adding and removing from a parent clip upon clicking different tabs.

Any idea what would be or could be causing this?  As far as I can tell nothing is over or obstructing the clip containing the text field and scroll bar.  The scroll bar actions work fine, which is next to the text field, however there seems to be no action going on as far as clicking links in the text field.  I can select text in this text field as well, so I'm a bit confused :<

Thanks for your help.

Edit - Textfield is selectable, I know they need to be for the event to work.

Comment: it works the first time until you remove/re-add the textfield? are you doing anything special when you remove it? does the textfield still have the event listener? can you add a click listener to the stage to see what the target/currentTarget is when you click the textfield?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about the layout and the behavior of the project, but from  my own bitter experience with TextEvents I learned that the less you mess around with the textfield, the better.

Maybe you should consider hiding the textfield instead of adding/removing it, i.e. changing the way the UI works without actually touching the affected elements in any way whatsoever.

If that's not possible, I'd try "rewriting" the text in the field and reattaching the event listener once the object is made visible again.

Hope you solve it quickly, texts are a pain in Flash.

Comment: Eek, thanks! I figured out the problem, and feel rather stupid now ._.  Problem was is I had the "tabs"/"buttons" for switching the text field clips over fairly close and manually added the fields to that clip without specifying a size D: They ended up being bigger than I expected, flowing over into the other clip stealing the click event :/

Comment: That would have been my second guess :D